# Remove plane from a glb object

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to remove a plane of my object to have a more accurate bounding box.
Currently I have the following object with its bounding box (calculated by [this script](https://github.com/sambler/addonsByMe/blob/master/create_bound_box.py))

[image]

As you can see, there is an extra point in the plane, so the bounding box is inaccurate.

[image]

Is there any way to remove the extra point in the plane? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean the point where all the dotted lines meet, I suspect that's the origin point of all the parts of the table (or at least an Empty that the parts are parented to). I'm not familiar with imported Sketchpad models but all those dotted lines are relationship lines.

Comment: There's a new [YT video](https://youtu.be/Ij8rfDCWlEg) by CGDive released today on importing Sketchfab models and using the addon. You might find some useful information there.

Comment: What do you mean by “the plane”?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a point in a plane, that is the empty to which all objects that form the table are parented to. It looks like you even show it in the Outliner as Sketchfab_model. If you delete that empty, you may have problems, but you can definitely move the parts of the table closer to it.